# MKMapView issue on iphone 6 plus, map embedded on view doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mapkit, iphone-6-plus

Does anyone have this issue on the iPhone 6 plus. When I embed the mapview on another view, I am getting a beige view instead, the annotations look ok and I can still scroll the 'map'. What's even more weird is that testing on the simulator, the same view appears as a bright pink view. Please see screenshots.

Note: It works ok in iPhones and simulators 4S, 5, 5S and 6.

iPhone 6 Plus:
[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

Simulator iPhone 6 Plus:
[image: Simulator iPhone 6 Plus]

iPhone 6:
[image: iPhone 6]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same case, but I was also having the bright pink color on the MKMapView. I solved it adding the MKMapView directly in the storyboard (or in a nib file if it's your case).

You can see more info on [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095103/ios8-mkmapview-framebuffer-error-during-rotation-when-autoresize-is-applied/30262774#30262774)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the Map Size. Try reducing the map size and it should work.